# CosmosDB Cassandra API - select in query throws exception

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

```
SELECT partition_int, clustering_int, value_string 
FROM test_ks1.test WHERE partition_int = ? AND clustering_int IN ?
```

Prepared select query with in clause throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.PrimitiveType cannot be cast to class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.ListType 
(com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.PrimitiveType and com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.ListType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
   at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.inspectType(CachingCodecRegistry.java:343)
   at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:256)
   at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.ValuesHelper.encodePreparedValues(ValuesHelper.java:112)
   at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultPreparedStatement.bind(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:159)
```

Using datastax oss driver - version 4.5.1 and cosmosDB.

The query works with cassadra as docker and works in cqlsh with CosmosDB.

Queries used:

- `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_ks1.test (partition_int int, value_string text, clustering_int int, PRIMARY KEY ((partition_int),clustering_int))`
- Prepare the statement: `INSERT INTO test_ks1.test (partition_int,clustering_int,value_string) values (?,?,?)`
- Insert values: 1,1,”a” | 1,2,”b”
- Prepare the statement: `SELECT partition_int, clustering_int, value_string FROM test_ks1.test WHERE partition_int = ? AND clustering_int IN ?`
- Execute with parameters `1,List.of(1,2)`
- The expected parameter is an integer and not list of integers

Sample code of the select prepared statement:

```
final CqlSessionBuilder sessionBuilder = CqlSession.builder()
     .withConfigLoader(loadConfig(sessionConfig));
CqlSession session = sessionBuilder.build();

PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(
   "SELECT partition_int, clustering_int,"
    + "value_string FROM test_ks1.test WHERE partition_int = ? "
    + "AND clustering_int IN ?");


com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.ResultSet rs = 
    session.execute(statement.bind(1,List.of(1, 2)));
```

Is there a workaround to use prepared select queries with in clause?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code that binds the variables?

Comment: @AlexOtt Sample code with the bind was added.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an work around like this:

```
//IDS you want to use;
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
// Multiply the number of question marks
String markers = StringUtils.repeat("?,", list.size()-1);
//Final query 
final String query = "SELECT * FROM test_ks1.test where clustering_int in ("+markers+" ?)";

PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(query);
BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind(list.toArray()).setIdempotent(true);
List<Row> rows  = session.execute(bound).all();
```

I have tried on my end and it works with me.

Now on your case you also have another parameter before the IN that you need to include in the parameter list but only after build the markers placeholder.